# epimorphisms between perfect groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is it true that for every infinite perfect group $P$, there exists a group $G$ with the following conditions:

1. $G$ and $P$ have the same cardinality;
2. $P$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $G$;
3. $G$ is not isomorphic to any quotient of $P$.

There is an interesting question suggested by YCor:  does there exist a countable perfect group $H$ such that every countable perfect group is isomorphic to a quotient of $H$?

Comment: Take $G = P \times Q$ where $Q$ is a simple group with cardinality greater than that of  $P$.

Comment: Are you assuming P is finite?

Comment: No, why should I be?

Comment: If P is infinite, how to determine Q? Pick a Q with infinite order? If so, it's not obvious to me why there are not epimorphisms of P onto Q. Would you please explain more?

Comment: For any infinite set $X$ the even permutations of $X$ with finite support form a simple group of cardinality $|X|$. If $|G| > |P|$ then there can be no surjective map from $P$ to $G$.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. I'll delete my question since it's sort of obvious to most people.

Comment: One can maybe ask the same question the restriction that $G$ has cardinal equal to $|P|$ (and $\aleph_0$ if $P$ is finite). The case of countable $P$ sounds not obvious then. This led me to a question possibly of independent interest: does there exist a countable perfect group $H$ such that every countable perfect group is isomophic to a quotient of $H$?

Comment: So I'd suggest to edit with the question with the cardinality restriction? it's harmless now because there's no posted answer so far.

Comment: @Ycor Thanks. Good idea. Just did as you suggested.

Comment: Derek and Yves, you seem to understand the question: can you edit it so that it makes some sense?

Comment: @Joël already done, you hurry too much :)

Comment: @ShijieGu I'm not sure my question (about existence of a sort of "universal" perfect countable group) is worth including here: possibly both questions are independent.

Comment: More precisely: if there's a perfect countable group $P$ admitting all perfect countable groups as quotients, then $P$ is solves the (current) main question in the negative. However if there's no such $P$, it does not help.

Comment: Thanks Ycor. I had the feel the the question could be interesting, but really I didn't understand it. Now it's clear.

Comment: Probably there is a result would be helpful for the second question. A.J. Berrick proved that every perfect group has to be a homomorphic image of a direct limit of free products of countable, perfect, locally free groups.